# W3 Total Cache still cached when user logging by Nicety Login

Tags: wordpress, caching, w3-total-cache

I have installed both W3 Total Cache and Nicety Login plugin in my site.

I set up W3 Total Cache with enable option "Don't cache pages for logged in users".
In the home page, I put the widget of Nicety Login for user logging.
But when user logged in using Nicety Login, the site still cached the home page with blank form likes not logged in use. But in fact, the real status is logged. I'm sure because I can do some actions that only logged in user can done.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this box?
Don't cache front page
*By default the front page is cached when using static front page in reading settings.

Comment: What happen if I display login form in a sidebar :(